# Problema con importar variables a otro archivo en PHP

Tags: php, mariadb

Holaa, estoy desarrollando un sistema de inicio y registro de sesión, el tema es que tengo un archivo llamado `config.php` que tiene todas las variables para la conexión con la base de datos (MariaDB).

```
<?php
define('USER', 'bla');
define('PASSWORD', 'bla');
define('HOST', 'bla');
define('DATABASE', 'bla');

try {
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD);
    echo "Conexion exitosa. \n";
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit("Ups! " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Ya desarrollado ese script, lo intenté importar en otro PHP que sería el de `register.php`, que contiene la página de registro en si.
Intenté `require_once, require, include,` y al intentar acceder a la variable `$connection` declarada en `config.php` no me sale, solo me dice que está indefinida...
Utilicé ésto mi `register.php` para ver qué errores podrían estar pasando.

```
ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', true );
```

Ningún error, todo limpio, `session_start()` lo puse encima de todo el html entonces no es un problema.
Aquí va algo... cuando ejecuto modo CLI el `register.php`, además de darme el output del html me sale ***Conexion exitosa.***, significa que `register.php` importó el script `config.php` pero no las variables de esta, descartando un problema de permisos y owning...
Pensaba que era un problema sobre que lo tengo en un try y no es una variable global, pero intenté hacerla global y nada de nada.

Estoy atascado con esto, agradecería un montón si pueden ayudarme =) xoxo

EDIT: Declaré la variable fuera del try...

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD);

try {
    $connection;
    echo "Conexion exitosa, yey! \n";
}
```

Aún así register.php no reconoce el $connection.

Comment: Una variable definida dentro de un bloque try/catch no está disponible **fuera** del bloque. Para eso debes primero definirla fuera del try (justo antes) y luego dentro del try ya puedes asignarla.

Comment: Subiré una actualización

Comment: y la idea es usar el config.php para almacenar las credenciales, siento que sería inseguro mantener variables con mis credenciales u conexiones en todos mis otros scripts...

Comment: A lo que se refiere @Benito-B es a que definas la variable como `$connection = null;` **antes** del `try / catch` y que dejaras el código del interior igual que antes. Prueba como te sugerimos y nos dices.

Comment: Aún así la variable no aparece en register.php, inicialicé como null la var connection y luego le asigné el valor de la conexión a mariadb en el try / catch :/

Comment: Como te indican los compañeros, tienes que definir la variable fuera del `try` y todo lo demás dejarlo como al principio. Si intentas conectar fuera del `try` el código no capturará las excepciones. O sea: `$connection=null; try { $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD); echo "Conexion exitosa. \n"; } catch (PDOException $e) { exit("Ups! " . $e->getMessage()); }` Y, en el contexto donde vayas a usar la conexión, verificas primero si la misma es válida con algo así: `if ($connection) { //aquí usar la conexion } else { echo "No connection" }`

Answer (score 0):

Como te indican los compañeros, tienes que definir la variable fuera del `try` y todo lo demás dejarlo como al principio. Si intentas conectar fuera del `try` el código no capturará las excepciones.

Otro aspecto que no se está tomando en cuenta aquí es que **en el contexto deberías verificar el estado de la conexión**, porque la misma podría fallar por algún motivo.

El código quedaría así:

```
<?php  
    define('USER', 'bla');
    define('PASSWORD', 'bla');
    define('HOST', 'bla');
    define('DATABASE', 'bla');
    
    $connection=null;
    
    try {
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD);
        echo "Conexion exitosa. \n";
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        #Convendría evitar esto en producción
        #estableciendo tu propia política 
        #de manejo de errores.
        #En algunos casos PDO revela las credenciales de conexión
        #Por lo que mostrar mensajes internos 
        #o dejar que se escriban en los logs de eror
        #puede ser muyyyyy peligroso
        exit("Ups! " . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

Y, en el contexto donde vayas a usar la conexión, verificas primero si la misma es válida con algo así:

```
if ($connection) { 
    //aquí usar la conexion 
} else { 
    //Aquí despliega tu política de manejo de errores
    echo "No connection";
}
```

En un código no deberías nunca asumir que algo tan delicado como la conexión funcionará siempre (la base de datos podría estar caída, te la pueden haber hackeado porque no usaste consultas preparadas, te pudieron haber puesto una bomba en el servidor, etc) por lo que convendría siempre verificar el estado de la misma antes de usarla.